# href tag image not appearing on addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling with a strange issue for last couple of days. I have href tag like below

```
<a id="opt" class="up" href="javascript:function(){e.preventDefault();}" onclick=" return shoptions(this.id);"></a>
```

And I am trying to apply another css class on click of this tag,in which i am trying to change the background image of the tag. The class is getting applied but the image is not displaying. Can anybody have an idea of this issue?

My javascript looks like below

```
 function shoptions(obj) {
        var a = $('#'+obj+'');
        if (a.hasClass('up')) {
            a.removeClass('up').addClass('down');
        }
        else {
            a.removeClass('down').addClass('up');
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And my css looks like below

```
a.up:link
{
background: #fff url(../egami/arrows_up.gif) scroll no-repeat left center !important;
padding: 2px 0 2px 16px !important;
}
a.down:link
{
background: #fff url(../egami/arrows_down.gif) scroll no-repeat left center !important;
padding: 2px 0 2px 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hello can you please create jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you can make everything more jQuery-style:

```
$('#opt').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('down up');
});
```

And get rid of inline handlers in HTML:

```
<a id="opt" class="up" href="#"></a>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3NYdF/

Comment: I have implemented same thing in my page. But it is working on first click, from second click the image is not changing. Any idea?

Comment: I have got it working after applying display: inline-block; in the CSS file. Any inputs on why we require this?

Comment: You need `inline-block` because your `a` tags collapses without content. When it's block or inline block you can set them a height. and it will become visible.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure ":link" is the selector you want to use? My understanding is that this selector only applies to link which the user has not visited. You may want to try removing this and just having "a.up" and "a.down".

Answer (score 0):

Why are using both `onClick` and `href`? Use only `href`:

```
<a id="opt" class="up" href="javascript:function(){e.preventDefault();};return shoptions(this.id);" ></a>
```

or only  `onClick`:

```
<a id="opt" class="up" onClick="function(){e.preventDefault();};return shoptions(this.id);" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you use `a.up:link` & `a.down:link`
use only  `a.up`  & `a.down`

```
a:link - a normal, unvisited link
a:visited - a link the user has visited
a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
a:active - a link the moment it is clicked
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)